# Magento Enterprise Permission Roles and Transitional Emails

Tags: magento, acl

I am working on a magento Enterprise website and the customer wants to create a new user with Z Scopes and Resoucrs.

The scope has "Transactional Emails" Selected
BUT
When the user with Z scope logs in, they can not see the ADD button.

I have fixed this issue

if the user group has resources set to ALL, it can add a transactional email.

But if we amend the resources (but to include Transactional Emails)
then the user gets "Access Denied"

Where abouts is this occurring?
How would i stop this happening (without amending CORE)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Transactional mails do not have a scope definition. They basically can be used in any store. So users with a limited scope can not edit any transactional emails or create new ones because this could effect all stores and might be unintended.